# Map Not Loading in Strange Situations

Tags: javascript, google-maps

One this site: www.michelesgranola.com, the Find a Store map isn't always loading.

If you go to the page directly, it tends to load: 
https://www.michelesgranola.com/store-locations/

However if you access the page via the "Find a Store" button on the slider on the front page, it doesn't usually load.

That said, sometimes it will load and sometimes it won't.

Any suggestions on how to go about solving this?

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me in firefox 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https:// - you need to set the link on your home page to link using the https:// protocol - right now it points to the page using the http:// protocol.

If you open your JavaScript console when you load that page (using http://) you'll see this message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.michelesgranola.com/wp/?sm-xml-search=1&lat=39.2904028&lng=-76.…76.61218930000001&query_type=all&limit=0&address=&city=&state=&zip=&pid=14. Origin http://www.michelesgranola.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

The map is trying to load data from a file using an https source and the browser's built-in security is not allowing you to do it when you are on an http domain.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out, Accessing it from the find-a-store on the front page, I tried 6 times in chrome and all 6 came out fine. Also 2 in firefox worked fine also. What browser are you using / testing with? older browsers may not be compatible with certain map functions.

As well, I have an app with a map myself, and I find it very fickle with slower devices. its about 50 - 50 whether it works or not when using a slower device. I don't think its anything I'm doing wrong since on faster devices it works perfect every time. I think google is a) fickle, and b) may have a time out where it gives up rendering. good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I know it works most of the time. Anyway, we figured it out. Thanks!